# Resubscribing at multiple business unit level

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am working at a code for a resubscribe for a custom unsubscribe centre that will update the Active Status back in Marketing Cloud & also updates a custom object in Salesforce; the update in Salesforce work fine & it also works the code when I hardcode the MID.

As we work with brand specific subscribers we need these updates to occur for specific MIDs. I have uploaded these in a non sendable data extension in MArketing Cloud & I am trying to pull them via amp script.

My code for the resubscribe piece is below:

```
    %%[ 
    SET @SubscriberKey = RequestParameter("SubscriberKey")
    SET @Email = RequestParameter("Email")
    SET @SalesforceID = Substring(@SubscriberKey, 0, 15)
    SET @MKTId = RequestParameter("MKTId") /* Id of the Marketing Cloud Consent Object found in the previous page */

UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Marketing_Consent__c", @MKTId,
                                     "Source__c","Resubscribed via RCH Unsubscribed Centre",
                                     "Opt_In__c", "True",
                                     "Reason__c", "I have decided to resubscribe",
                                     "Assumed_Opt_in__c", "True"

                                    )



/* Create and populate a RetrieveRequest */
SET @retrieveRequest = CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")
SetObjectProperty(@retrieveRequest, "ObjectType", "DataExtensionObject[Accounts to Reconsent]")

AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","Business unit name")
AddObjectArrayItem(@retrieveRequest, "Properties","MID")

/* Execute the Retrieve */
SET @Members = InvokeRetrieve(@retrieveRequest)

SET @MembersCount = RowCount(@Members)
/* Iterate over the data */

FOR @i = 1 to @MembersCount DO
    SET @currentSub = Row(@Members, @i)
    SET @properties = Field(@currentSub,"Properties")
    Set @numofProperties = ROWCOUNT(@properties)

FOR @j = 1 to @numofProperties DO

    SET @currentProp = Row(@properties, @j)
    Set @Field1= FIELD(@currentProp ,"Name") 
    Set @Field2= FIELD(@currentProp ,"Value") 

/*Update the unsubscribe from all list*/  
SET @ll_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")

SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"EmailAddress", @Email)
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"SubscriberKey", @SubscriberKey)

SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @Field2)
SetObjectProperty(@client, "IDSpecified", "true")
SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub, "Client", @client)

SetObjectProperty(@ll_sub,"Status","Active")
Set @options = CreateObject("UpdateOptions")
Set @save = CreateObject("SaveOption")
SetObjectProperty(@save,"SaveAction","UpdateAdd")
SetObjectProperty(@save,"PropertyName","Status")
AddObjectArrayItem(@options,"SaveOptions", @save)

/* Here is where we actually update the Subscriber object */
Set @update_sub = InvokeUpdate(@ll_sub, @update_sub_status, @update_sub_errorcode, @options)

NEXT @j
NEXT @i]%%

My Subscriber has:
<br>
Key: %%=v(@SubscriberKey)=%%
<br>
Email: %%=v(@Email)=%%
<br>
Marketing Consent: %%=v(@MKTId)=%%
<br>
THANKS FOR RESUBSCRIBING!
```

I have used this documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/retrieveRows.htm

and this piece of code pulls all the MIDs for which i need the resubscribe to happen.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Giulietta